# Dropdown menu with sliding submenus

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I have been using a zendesk system and on a ticket submission page there is a dropdown menu with sliding submenus that can be navigated left and right. I'm desperately trying to find how to do something similar. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is there a javascript plug in that does something similar?

When you click on the menu item with the arrow, the submenu appears and you get the option to navigate back a level at the top.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Like [this](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/mdbootstrap/949080)?

Comment: Sadly not, as that one makes a new submenu which comes out to the left, but thanks for the suggestion. The images I've given above show two different menus. The second one is what shows when 'Ask a Question' is picked from the first menu option.

Comment: This is the closest thing I've found. https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Multi-level-jQuery-Dropdown-Plugin/